# Generic types inside List in Scala

Tags: scala, lift, lift-json

I have following code snippet:

```
val serializedClasses: List[MongoMetaRecord[MongoRecord[_]]] = List(User, Email)
```

Unfortunately I can't get exact type info from the elements and following code fails:

```
serializedClasses.map(c => new RecordSerializer(c))

[error] JsonFormats.scala:19: inferred type arguments [_$1] do not conform to class RecordSerializer's type parameter bounds [T <: net.liftweb.mongodb.record.MongoRecord[T]]
[error]   implicit val jsonformats = DefaultFormats + (new ObjectIdSerializer)  + (new RecordSerializer(DirectMessage)) + (new RecordSerializer(User)) ++ serializedClasses.map(c => new RecordSerializer(c))
```

Here is `RecordSerializer.scala`

```
object RecordSerializer {
  def apply[T <: MongoRecord[T]](meta: MongoMetaRecord[T]) = new RecordSerializer(meta)
}

class RecordSerializer[T <: MongoRecord[T]](meta: MongoMetaRecord[T]) extends Serializer[MongoRecord[T]] {

  def deserialize(implicit format: Formats): PartialFunction[(TypeInfo, JValue), MongoRecord[T]] = {
case (TypeInfo(clazz, parametrizedType), json: JValue) if(JsonFormats.serializedClassesNames.contains(clazz.getSimpleName)) => {
  meta.fromJValue(json).openOr(throw new MappingException("Couldn't convert"))
    }
  }

  def serialize(implicit format: Formats): PartialFunction[Any, JValue] = {
    case rec: MongoRecord[_] => rec.asJValue
  }
}
```

Comment: This is probably more appropriate to post on programmers.stackexchange.com.  Maybe someone should move it there?

Comment: Stackoverflow is not for programmers anymore ?

Comment: Sure it is, but they've made a specific part of the site for questions about code.  Questions about tools still go on stackoverflow.  Hopefully a moderator will correct me if I'm wrong about that because I spend 95% of my time on programmers and 5% on stackoverflow.  I've flagged your question for moderator attention, so someone will likely move it or respond here shortly.

Comment: Thanks. I'll ask code questions on programmers next time.

Comment: @GlenPeterson You can most certainly ask programmer questions here. In fact, this question is exactly why this site was created in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not clear on what the question is here.  How to get it to compile?  RecordSerializer takes a typed MongoRecord and your List does not capture the type of its items.  If you want to get this to work you'll either need to capture the record types (you could use an HList like the one provided by Shapeless to capture the type of each item) or you'll need to rewrite your RecordSerializer so that it gets it's type information from the record at runtime only and isn't dependent on knowing a compile time type.

Comment: Thanks I think I was looking for HList here.